# How to remove hyperlinks in the Look up field

Tags: lookup-column

How do you remove hyperlinks in the Look up field using jQuery in SharePoint?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 or 2010?

Comment: And what code did you try sofar

Comment: $('a[href*="mylink").contents().unwrap();

Comment: I need it in 2010....I have tried  $('a[href*="mylink").contents().unwrap(); so far...Its working fine when the view is normal..BUt when I try to group fields then the code is not working..Can somebody help on this

Comment: I have tried lot of methods ....They are not working in a grouped view

Comment: try it on click of `ms-commentexpand-icon`. like `$('.ms-commentexpand-icon').click(function(){$('a[href*="mylink").contents().unwrap();})`; @DheerajKontham

Comment: I have just tried ..But it  dint work

Comment: Can we do it using Workflows..am not that good at workflows..Is there any possibility that we could try with workflows?

Answer (score 3):

**Using jQuery:** You can try using Content Editor Web Part. Find the element and `unwrap()`.

```
$('#myLink').contents().unwrap();
```

[There are many ways to remove hyperlink using jQuery](https://www.google.com.bd/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=remove%20hyperlink%20in%20jquery). Use which one suites you best.

**For SharePoint 2013:** You can use **[CSR](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)**. Let's say I have following list with a lookup column which allows multiple selection.

[image]

Following code will remove the hyperlink from lookup column.

```
"Internal Name of the lookup column": {
                   View: function(ctx) { 
                     var lookUpValues = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
                     var lookUpDisplayTitles = [];
                     lookUpValues.forEach(function(lookup){
                       lookUpDisplayTitles.push(lookup.lookupValue);
                     });
                     return lookUpDisplayTitles.join("; "); 
                   }
```

`ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]` returns lookup values as array of objects. It will always return lookup value as array. It does not matter whether you have allowed multiple selection or not. Object inside the array looks like

```
{
    lookupId: 2,
    lookupValue: "Active Directory",
    isSecretFieldValue: false
}
```

So I have pushed all `lookupValue` in an array named `lookUpDisplayTitles`. Finally, I have joined them by `"; "` and returned it to the view. So my current view looks like

[image]

Find the full code below and use [Cisar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en)(developed by **[Andrey Markeev](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/1430/andrey-markeev)**) for **CSR**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

    function getBaseHtml(ctx) {
        return SPClientTemplates["_defaultTemplates"].Fields.default.all.all[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType][ctx.BaseViewID](ctx);
    }

    function init() {

        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

            // OnPreRender: function(ctx) { },

            Templates: {

                //     View: function(ctx) { return ""; },
                //     Header: function(ctx) { return ""; },
                //     Body: function(ctx) { return ""; },
                //     Group: function(ctx) { return ""; },
                //     Item: function(ctx) { return ""; },
                Fields: {
                    "Internal Name Of The Lookup Column": {
                        View: function(ctx) {
                            var lookUpValues = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
                            var lookUpDisplayTitles = [];
                            lookUpValues.forEach(function(lookup) {
                                lookUpDisplayTitles.push(lookup.lookupValue);
                            });
                            return lookUpDisplayTitles.join("; ");
                        },
                        //             EditForm: function(ctx) { return ""; },
                        //             DisplayForm: function(ctx) { return ""; },
                        //             NewForm: function(ctx) { return ""; }
                    }
                },
                //     Footer: function(ctx) { return ""; }

            },

            // OnPostRender: function(ctx) { },

            ListTemplateType: 100

        });
    }

    RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/HyperLinkRemove.js"), init);
    init();

});
```